# Identify symmettry in BdG hamltonian

Tags: symmetry, superconductivity, second-quantization

I am confused about what symmetry is responsible for the $(E,-E)$ pairing of the energy levels in a superconducting hamiltonian.

Consider the superconducting Hamiltonian
$$
\mathcal{H} = 
\Psi^\dagger
H
\Psi
\qquad
\text{for}
\qquad
H = \begin{pmatrix}
h & \Delta
\\
\Delta^\dagger & - h^T
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad \Psi = \begin{pmatrix}
C_{\uparrow}
\\
C_{\downarrow}^\dagger
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $C_{\sigma} = (c_{1,\sigma},c_{2,\sigma},c_{3,\sigma},\ldots)$ is the vector of orbital annihilation operators in the position basis, we additionally assume that the hopping term is hermitian $h = h^\dagger$, and pairing term is symmetric $\Delta=\Delta^T$, however in this instance they are otherwise assumed to be otherwise general complex matrices.

It is straightforward to see that the eigenvalues come in $(E,-E)$ pairs due to the symmettry of the BdG Hamiltonian
$$
O H O^T = - H^T \qquad \text{for} \qquad O = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1
\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
What symmetry is this?

It seems it can be reframed as the symmettry of the Hamiltonian under a transformation $S$ with acts as $S c_{r,\sigma} S^{-1} = \sigma c_{r,-\sigma}$ and $S i S^{-1} = i$.
$$
S \mathcal{H} S^{-1} = S \Psi^\dagger H \Psi S^{-1} = \Psi^T O^T H O (\Psi^\dagger)^T = - \Psi^\dagger O^T H^T  O \Psi = \Psi^\dagger H \Psi = \mathcal{H}.
$$

This looks like time reversal symmetry, however time reversal symmetry has the additional action of complex conjugation, that is $T i T^{-1} = - i$, whereas $S$ does not.